# PHP mailer form issue when sending to Office365 account

Tags: php, phpmailer, office365

My client findspace.co.uk is name registered and hosted with Fasthosts. However since the summer they migrated their email to Office365 and since then the PHP mailer form at findspace.co.uk/pages/arrange.php is returning the error

> We're sorry - there was a problem sending this email - please try again.

I've tried changing the smtp email host from fasthosts to Office 365:

```
<?php include_once("../class/class.phpmailer.php"); ?>
<?php
/********************************* INITIALISE PAGE SETTINGS ******************************************/

$page_title = "Contact Us";

$website_name = "Findspace";
$mail_host = "smtp.office365.com"; // email host
$mail_emailsource = "kp@findspace.co.uk"; // from email address
$mail_emailrecipient = "kp@findspace.co.uk"; // recipient

$mail_username = "contact@findspace.co.uk";
$mail_password = "MYPASSWORD";
```

But it's still not working. I'm no php expert and I can't figure out where things are going wrong. I wonder if it's an Office365 exchange account filtering issue?

Hi Len - I can't seem to find the bit that does the initializing - me just being a bit thick I think. The form has worked for 5 years up until my client changed email hosting to Office365 in the summer so I'm not certain it's the actual form - or perhaps it's the information i'm using for the hostname etc.

Comment: Can we see the bit of code that does the sending? What do your SMTP logs say (if you have access to them)?

Comment: Hi Halfer - thanks for responding. Is this the code you wanted to see?

Comment: Hang on - I can't seem to paste in the code - its too long. Was there a specific bit?

Comment: It should be `$mailer = new MailerThing(); ... $mailer->send();` or something thereabouts. I would expect it to be 5-10 more lines of code? I'm not a mail expert, but as it stands there isn't much to go on.

Comment: Also, check your PHP logs. And it's worth checking you have the SMTP credentials right as well, check them in a mail client.

Comment: Hi - I couldn't findanything that begins $mailer. How would I check my PHP logs?

Comment: [Wed Dec 10 20:02:45 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  fsockopen() [<a href='function.fsockopen'>function.fsockopen</a>]: unable to connect to outlook.office365.com:25 (Network is unreachable) in /home/linuxscript01/f/findspace.co.uk-1076142901/user/htdocs/class/class.smtp.php on line 105
[Wed Dec 10 20:02:45 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: command_completed in /home/linuxscript01/f/findspace.co.uk-1076142901/user/htdocs/pages/arrange.php on line 198

Comment: This is a sample of the error log - which is quite long!

Comment: OK, two errors to look into. You have no network connectivity to office365, and you have an undefined variable. These are both broad topics - can you debug? If you want someone to take a look at the variable issue, then paste in the bit that is going wrong, around line 198, in your question here.

Comment: (I didn't _literally_ mean `$mailer` - it was an example. You have access to the code, I don't - so you'll have to see where PHP Mailer is instantiated with a `new` keyword.)

Comment: You are using an old version of PHPMailer - I suggest you [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). It's quite likely that Office365 wants encryption, so start with [the gmail example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) and adapt that. If you still have trouble, [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Comment: In those log messages, you can see it's connecting to port 25. It's very likely that this is blocked. You should be using TLS on port 587, which is more secure and less likely to be blocked.

Comment: Thanks halfer and Synchro - I'll try these suggestions and report back.

Answer (score 1):

The $mail_host setting for that domain is:

```
findspace-co-uk.mail.protection.outlook.com
```

The IP is:

```
213.199.154.87
```

http://mxlookup.online-domain-tools.com/

I think you should take a look at this page and compare it to how you are initializing phpmailer on your end.:

```
http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=examplebsmtp
```

Comment: Hi Len - thanks for responding. Shall I just replace the hostname with findspace-co-uk.mail.protection.outlook.com and try that?

Comment: I'd give that a shot and see what happens.

Comment: Also, these settings might help if you still have  aproblem:
SMTP Security: Enable TLS
Port: 587

Comment: Do I enable the Port:587 in the PHP file or elsewhere?

Comment: From the snippet of code you have posted, it appears you may not be initializing phpmailer correctly or, if you are, it comes later in the code. Can you post the portion of the code that sets the phpmailer properties? Just post it to your original question.

Comment: Please don't link to obsolete examples. You can find an appropriate example in [the current PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps).